# jQuery flip containers without class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 card containers which flip individually if you click on each one.

Afterwards a button which flips them all at once (see below). What im trying to do is if a card is flipped individually the class `.hover` is added and if you hit the button to flip them all it should flip the 3 remaining containers adding the same class. And if this button is hit again, remove the class `.hover`.

```js
$("#rotateAll").click(function() {
  var card = $('.card-container');
  if (card.hasClass('hover')) {
    card.removeClass('hover');
  } else {
    card.addClass('hover');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="rotateAll" title="link title" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Ver todas las tarifas</a>
```

All I want to happen is the button to flip any remaining container that hasn´t been flipped.

Comment: Is there an issue with the code? You've only told us what you're trying to do. It would help to know what the issues you have are, and also to see a more complete sample of your code, including the HTML and CSS. Finally, note that the `if` statement can be replaced with just `card.toggleClass('hover')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The issue is that right now if you hit the button to flip them all at once it works, but if there is one or more flipped individually and you hit the button to flip the X remaining containers it will first remove the class from the first flipped and if you hit it again it will flip all four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a global variable named `flipped` first like so:

```
var flipped = false;
```

Then make your toggle function look like this:

```
$("#rotateAll").click(function() {
    var cards = $(".card-container");
    cards.each(function(card) {
        if (flipped) {
            card.removeClass("hover");
        } else {
            card.addClass("hover"),
        }
    })
    flipped = !flipped;
})
```

This adds or removes the `hover` class from all cards regardless of individual flips.

Comment: I had to change inside the if `card` to `cards` for it to work, and you have a comma in your else instead of a semicolon :P. Why wont it work with `card` only?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could select all the cards and apply your logic for each one.

```
 $("#rotateAll").click(function () {
  var cards = $('.card-container');
  $.each(cards, function (i, card) {
    if (card.hasClass('hover')) {
      card.removeClass('hover');
    } else {
      card.addClass('hover');
    }
  })
})
```